# PHP Echo Disappears After Parent Div Is Set To Position Fixed And Top 0

Tags: php, css

Is there any way to solve this problem? I have a PHP `echo` which works if position fixed and top 0 is not set on it's parent.

I tried to use `z-index` on the `div`, but nothing happens. I tried everything I could.

```
<div class="nav-buttons">
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo '<a class="nav-register-button" href="account.php">My Account</a>';
        echo '<a class="nav-login-button" href="logout.php">Sign Out</a>';
    } else{
        echo '<a class="nav-register-button nav-button" href="account.php">Register</a>';
        echo '<a class="nav-login-button nav-button" href="login.php">Sign In</a>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

That's the code related to PHP.

```
.header{
    background: url("../Images/header.jpg");
    height: 68px;
    border-bottom: 5px #CEAB57 solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

That's my CSS.
Please help me guys.

Comment: The CSS code you applied is not connected to the HTML code you shown. Also, if something disappears after a "CSS" change, then if has nothing to do with PHP. It's purely HTML+CSS issue, and as it stands now, there is nothing we can say. Provide at least valid HTML and CSS parts, or a link so we can debug,

Comment: are aware that CSS has nothing to do with PHP ?